# Would the Voyager probes go backwards affected by the strong interstellar wind beyond Heliosphere?

Tags: voyager, solar-wind, interstellar-medium

The Heliosheath is the solar wind piles up as it presses outward against the approaching wind in interstellar space. It seems the balance in pressure between Heliopause and interstellar wind causes the solar wind to turn back and flow down the tail of the heliosphere.

[image: PIA22835]

<sup>[PIA22835: Two Interstellar Travelers](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA22835) - Illustration shows plasma flow lines both inside and outside the heliopause. The direction of the solar plasma is different from the direction of the interstellar plasma.</sup>

My main concern is the interstellar wind so strong and causes this phenomenon, why wouldn't the Voyager probes go backwards affected by the interstellar wind after they went beyond the <s>Heliosheath</s> Heliosphere? Or in fact they are gradually slowing down?

Answer (score 4):

No. The interstellar medium is [almost a vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_medium), just like the heliosphere. In fact, this is a lower pressure [than we've ever created on Earth](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52220/have-we-managed-to-make-a-perfect-vacuum), at 1-1000 atoms/cm<sup>3</sup>, so 10<sup>20</sup> times lower than atmosperic pressure on Earth.